# Text-align without float for menubar with css

Tags: html, css, alignment, css-float, menubar

I'd like to have at the following menubar three items at the left side, the other one (eMail) on the right one.

```css
ul.menubar {
    list-style-type: none; /* entfernt Bulletpoints */
    margin-left: 5px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #D4D4D4;
}

ul.menubar li {
    float: left; /* Elemente sind linksbünding NEBENEINANDER angeordnet */
    margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
}


#eMail {
    position: right;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
    float: right;
}

ul.menubar li a {
    color: black;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    padding:15px; /* Innenabstand im Element bis zum Rand */
    text-decoration: none; /* entfernt Unterstreichen der Elemente*/
    transition: 0.3s; /* Animation zu :hover*/
    font-family: Century Gothic;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menubar" id=topmenubar>
        <li><a href="#linkHome">Logo</a></li> <!-- bedeutet '#' gleicher Link + Ergänzung?-->
        <li><a href="#linkContact">Contact</a></a></li>
        <li><a href="#linkAbout">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#linkEmail" "id="eMail">eMail</a></li>
</ul>
```

As I see *float* (and *text-align*/*position* as well) doesn't work. What can I do to move the eMail link to the right side?

Regards, Jonas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select the last element which is email with the [nth-child()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) selector.
And the following code place the email tab to the right of the menu.

```
li:nth-child(4) {
    float: right !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the `id="eMail"` attribute off the `<a>` and to the parent `<li>` element, as those `li`s have floating styles on them that are determining the placement of the `a` elements inside. Then `float: right;` should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
.menubar li:last-of-type {
 float: right;
}
```

Right after the `.menubar li` rule you have now, and delete the entire `#eMail`-rule